# How can I flash my Galaxy 5 (GT-I5500) via Linux?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-5, rom-flashing

I like to know if there's a way to flash my Galaxy 5 (I5500) via Linux. I found Heimdall, but it only works with Samsung's Galaxy S.

Comment: I've seen people post about using Odin and some indication that Heimdall may also work.  I personally would experiment, but I understand if you don't want to take the risk.

Comment: I tried to use Heimdall but it's not compatible with G5. Have an alternative to it?

Comment: Have you tried Odin over Wine?

Answer (score 1):

you can use mobile odin to flash ROMs directly from your device.Galaxy 5 (I5500) is supported. See the thread at xda developers: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1347899

Answer (score 0):

Many people at xda make tar's from update.zip files. Maybe there is a way to make update.zip cwm flashable files from odin flashable tar files.

Answer (score 0):

I could never get Heimdall to work properly.  I wound up flashing my ROM directly from ADB instead:

```
adb shell
/sbin/recovery --wipe_data
/sbin/recovery --update_package=SDCARD:romname.zip
```

(romname being whatever your zip file's name is, and at the root of the SD card)